# Wso2 Ei 6.3 self signed certification error

Tags: ssl, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am getting below certification error while i am trying to call any API https://:8243/ from a react based frontend application. I have defined my rest API in wso2 EI 6.3. I am not using wso2 APIM.

What i did to resolve this issue:
1. I created a new self signed certificate and created a new key store. Updated carbon.xml, axis2.xml file. Restart the server. I am able to see my certificate in wso2 Ei GUI.
2. I accepted the certificate in browser.

But still i am not able to get rid of this error.

Is this error coming due to self signed certificate? If i will be using any CA signed certificate then this issue will not be there?
Any help or pointer is highly appreciated.

```
[2020-04-07 08:54:48,841] [-1] [] [HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.SourceHandler} -  I/O error: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1647)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.fatal(SSLEngineImpl.java:1615)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.recvAlert(SSLEngineImpl.java:1781)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:1070)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.readNetRecord(SSLEngineImpl.java:896)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:766)
        at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:624)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doUnwrap(SSLIOSession.java:245)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.doHandshake(SSLIOSession.java:280)
        at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:410)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:119)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:159)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:338)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:316)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:277)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:105)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:586)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

BR//
Vipin Nirwal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue. I followed the below steps.
I created a self CA first. Then created a certificate signed by my own CA. Import the root certificate of my CA into the browser As this CA needs to be trusted by browser.
After this update carbon.xml,  files inside axis2 directory and catalina-server.xml file with proper jks file and password for keystores.
Restarted the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to debug it yourself by enabling SSL debug logs in the EI server. In the SSL logs, you can check whether the client certificate and the server certificate is matching. Have a look at the following blog.

https://medium.com/@nipunadilhara/enabling-ssl-debug-logs-for-wso2-products-30833d5de88e